# Excel Shift Data down after Insert

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully someone can help me out here :(

In a sequence of workbooks (never a good idea :)), a user runs a macro which copies data from `Workbook1` and inserts it using `Insert Shift:=xlDown` in `Workbook2`.

The problem is this: there is taller rows and a grouped textbox below the destination, and instead of shifting these down, the macro leaves the row size large and the textbox doesn't move.

I have set the textbox group to `Move and size with cells` and tried `CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove` but it seems to make no difference.

Can somebody help please?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

Here is the full code: (commented out original idea, added suggestion below)

```
Sub MakeQuote2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sourceRange As Range, loopRange As Range
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim FRow As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim p As Long
m = Sheets("Workbook1").Rows.Count
FRow = Sheets("Workbook1").Range("A" & m).End(xlUp).Row

Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A9:E" & FRow)
Set targetRange = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Documents\Trial1.xltm").Sheets("Workbook2").Range("A4")

sourceRange.Copy
Sheets("Workbook2").Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Insert 'Select
'Selection.Insert 'Shift:=xlDown
p = FRow + 5
Sheets("Workbook2").Rows("4:" & p).Copy
Sheets("Workbook2").Rows("4:4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Workbook2").Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("Copy.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me. On what object do you use the `Insert` on? Providing a more complete code could help.

Comment: @dePatinkin could anything be done with this code? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy entire rows, paste will shift everything down. If your copy source has only several columns, the data shifts down but no rows format or objects shift with it. This is true in Excel, not only in VBA.

This code works for me (I changed some of the references to test it in my environment):

```
Set sourceRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A9:E" & FRow).EntireRow '<-- Added EntireRow here.
Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4") '<-- This is never used. 
sourceRange.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Insert
```

- The only addition I made is to add `EntireRow` to the source range to copy. If you need only columns `A:E` I would suggest you insert blank rows according to `FRow - 9`, and then copy and paste `A:E` in the added rows.
- Note that you are mixing up references `Sheets("Workbook1")`, `ActiveSheet` in your original code, and you never use `targetRange`.

### Addition

As mentioned in the first note, to add blank rows before you paste only the relevant columns, you can use something like this code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("4:" & FRow - 9 + 4).EntireRow.Insert 
Set sourceRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A9:E" & FRow)
Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4") 
sourceRange.Copy
targetRange.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: thanks - this works but i have data in columns after `E` so your code actually copies data that I don't want to keep.... could it be modified? Thanks very much

Comment: As I noted in my answer, in this case you need to insert blank rows before you paste.

Comment: Thanks... just what I was looking for @dePatinkin

Answer (score 2):

If you want below text boxes to move and size with the cells above then it does not suffice to use

```
.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Instead you need to use

```
.EntireRow.Insert
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me :( - see edit to original post for full code (if this helps)